# How do I post ajax data in which an element contains data like 'http://www.example.com?i=12&j=34'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
var desc = "www.google.com?i=12&j=34"
$.ajax({
            url: 'controller/function',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({tDescription:desc}),
            beforeSend: function(){
                //Do Something
            },
            success: function(msg){
                //Do Something                
            }
        });
```

In `$_POST` contains like below

```
tDescription: www.google.com?i=12
j:34
```

How do I retrieve Total desc as it is

Comment: You must encode that '&' char in http request body,you may want function `encodeURIComponent` to do this

Comment: The desc variable is splitting in two...how to get total desc as it is

Comment: Can you suggest same function in jquery

Comment: I think Musa have gave you answer below,and php may need a decode function which you can easily get from google,good luck :)

Comment: thank u for responding,have to try now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode you data.

```
data: ({tDescription:encodeURIComponent(desc)}),
```

**When to use which?**
The **escape()** method does not encode the + character which is interpreted as a space on the server side as well as generated by forms with spaces in their fields. Due to this shortcoming and the fact that this function fails to handle non-ASCII characters correctly, you should avoid use of escape() whenever possible. The best alternative is usually encodeURIComponent().

**escape()** will not encode: @*/+

Use of the **encodeURI()** method is a bit more specialized than escape() in that it encodes for URIs [REF] as opposed to the querystring, which is part of a URL. Use this method when you need to encode a string to be used for any resource that uses URIs and needs certain characters to remain un-encoded. Note that this method does not encode the ' character, as it is a valid character within URIs.

**encodeURI()** will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'

Lastly, the **encodeURIComponent()** method should be used in most cases when encoding a single component of a URI. This method will encode certain chars that would normally be recognized as special chars for URIs so that many components may be included. Note that this method does not encode the ' character, as it is a valid character within URIs.

**encodeURIComponent()** will not encode: ~!*()'

Comment: What if the desc contains normal text

Comment: encodeURIComponent() isn't worked for me,so I have used data: ({tDescription:encode(desc)}),

Comment: Don't do that. When you pass an object to jQuery there, it will encode it for you.

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` your content and you can parse that at the destination.

Comment: The data is coming from a string, not a form.